# Can't get Pause Button to resume time properly - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, button, timer, pause

I am coding a Stopwatch Timer in Excel, and I am trying to add a pause button that will stop the timer, also resume when clicked the 2nd time. I have it almost working, but when it resumes it does not continue the stopwatch at the same time, but rather includes all of the elapsed time. The way I have it working is that when you click the pause button it adds the value of "Paused" to a cell and sets the application to "False". If the button is clicked and the cell already says "Paused" it will empty the cell value and call the StartTimer sub and start the timer again.

*Example of problem: If I press the button at 1min and 3secs, wait 3mins and resume the timer, it starts counting again at 4min and 3secs.*

**Example of goal: If I press the button at 1min and 3secs, wait 3mins and resume the timer, it should start counting again at 1min and 4secs.**

Here is my current code that i've been working on:

```
Dim NextTick As Date, t As Date
Sub StartStopWatch()
t = Time
Call StartTimer
End Sub

Sub StartTimer()
NextTick = Time + TimeValue("00:00:01")
Range("M1").Value = Format(NextTick - t - TimeValue("00:00:01"), "hh:mm:ss")
Application.OnTime NextTick, "StartTimer"
End Sub

Sub StopTimer()

On Error Resume Next
Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=NextTick, Procedure:="StartTimer", Schedule:=False

End Sub

Sub ResetTimer()
Range("M1").ClearContents
Range("N1").ClearContents
Range("L2").ClearContents
End Sub

Sub PauseButton()

If Range("L2").Value = "" Then

Range("L2").Value = "Paused"

Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=NextTick, Procedure:="StartTimer", Schedule:=False

Else
Range("L2").ClearContents
Call StartTimer

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not reset the start time when paused.  But resetting the start time would lose previous elapsed periods.  One approach to this problem is to record the number of elapsed seconds each time the clock stops.  Subsequence start/stops are added to the running elapsed counter.  There is a reset method so you can begin again from zero.

```
Private StartTime As Date           ' Stores timer start time.
Private StopTime As Date            ' Stores timer end time.
Private ElapsedTime As Integer      ' Store number of seconds between start and end time.
Private TimerRunning As Boolean     ' True when the timer is running.


' Resets ElapsedTime and running status.
Public Sub ResetTimer()

    ElapsedTime = 0
    If TimerRunning Then TimerRunning = False
End Sub

' Starts the timer.
Public Sub StartTimer()

    ' Record start time.
    StartTime = Time
    TimerRunning = True
End Sub

' Stops the timer.
' Displays elapsed seconds.
Public Sub StopTimer()

    ' Record end time.
    StopTime = Time
    TimerRunning = False

    ' Calculate numebr of seconds clock was running for.
    ' Add total to any previous runs.
    ElapsedTime = ElapsedTime + DateDiff("S", StartTime, StopTime)
    MsgBox "Clock ran for " & ElapsedTime & " seconds", vbInformation, "Clock Stopped"
End Sub

' Pause the timer.
Public Sub PauseTimer()

    ' Check current status.
    If TimerRunning Then

        ' Stop the clock, capture the end time
        ' but do not reset the timer.
        StopTimer
    Else

        ' Restart the timer.
        StartTimer
    End If
End Sub
```

Users only really need access to the pause and reset functions.  You could make the start and stop functions internal [private methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_class_data_pattern).

I've stored the elapsed time in an integer.  Date and time variables should be used to record when an event occurred, rather than the duration.  Why?  Because a time variable supports values from `00:00:00` -> `23:59:59` (times of the day).  This leaves no room to record events that lasted longer than a day.  You can always format the int when displaying.

Answer (score 0):

I havn't understood how exactly your code works and I tried a couple of things but its not working. Basically what I was trying to to was to take the time from the cell M1 itself the next time it starts and then continue from there itself. Look at this code, maybe it will help.

```
Dim NextTick As Date, t As Date, continue_time As Date
Sub StartStopWatch()
If Range("L2").Value = "" Then
    t = Time
    Range("L2").ClearContents
Else
    t = TimeValue(Range("M1").Text) - Time
End If
't = Time
Call StartTimer
End Sub

Sub StartTimer()
'If Range("L2").Value = "" Then
'    continue_time = Time
'Else
'    continue_time = TimeValue(Range("M1").Text)
'End If

NextTick = Time + TimeValue("00:00:01")
Range("M1").Value = Format(NextTick - t - TimeValue("00:00:01"), "hh:mm:ss")
Application.OnTime NextTick, "StartTimer"
End Sub

Sub StopTimer()

On Error Resume Next
Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=NextTick, Procedure:="StartTimer", Schedule:=False

End Sub

Sub ResetTimer()
Range("M1").ClearContents
Range("N1").ClearContents
Range("L2").ClearContents
End Sub

Sub PauseButton()

If Range("L2").Value = "" Then

Range("L2").Value = "Paused"

Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=NextTick, Procedure:="StartTimer", Schedule:=False

Else

Call StartStopWatch

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually just figured it out using a code that counts integers and then changed the formatting to mm:ss.

**Solution: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=153966**